# while loop increment in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
function diamond(n) {
  if (n % 2 == 0 || n < 1) return null
  var x = 0,
    add, diam = line(x, n);
  while ((x += 2) < n) {
    add = line(x / 2, n - x);
    diam = add + diam + add;
  }
  return diam;
}
function repeat(str, x) {
  return Array(x + 1).join(str);
}
function line(spaces, stars) {
  return repeat(" ", spaces) + repeat("*", stars) + "\n";
}
console.log(diamond(5));
```

The code prints the diamond shape using asterisks.
I was trying to understand this code (other person's code).
I thought the result would look like

```
  *
 ***
*****
*****
*****
 ***
  *
```

But it worked perfectly well, and I realized the part `while ((x +=2) < n)`
did make difference.
So my question is: what is the difference between `while ((x += 2) < n) { ... }` and `while (x < n) { ... x += 2 }`?

Answer (score 2):

```
 ((x+=2) < n)
```

x+=2 is a shorthand for x=x+2;

if x=0 initially the condition that would be checked would be 2 < n

```
(x < n) {...x += 2}
```

if x=0 initially the condition that would be checked would be 0 < n

Main difference is you are incrementing first and then checking the condition in first one while in second one you check and then increment x.

Comment: Oh, so the statements in while loop have been looped through only two times?

Comment: I totally get it. Thanks so much !

Comment: Glad I was able to help:)

Answer (score 2):

So your question is what's the difference between...

```
while ((x+=2) < n) {}
```

AND

```
while(x < n) { x+=2 }
```

The main difference is that in the first example, the `x` gets the 2 added on and is then compared to the value of `n`, whereas in the second example, `x` is compared to `n` before the 2 has been added and will therefore most likely run 1 more loop than you would expect